# WMI methods for Hyper-V network management is failing on Windows 2012

Tags: wmi, hyper-v

I have been trying to use WMI classes (using C++) to manage Virtual Switches in Hyperv like Creation,Deletion, Attach a Virtual Network to a VM etc. I was able to do everything perfectly on Windows 2008 R2. But none of them are working fine on Windows 2012.

For example when I create  an externalnetwork I call a method called CreateSwitchPort on the object of the class Msvm_VirtualSwitchManagementService. It's working on 2k8R2 but fails with out parameter return value as 32768 which means failure. Can anyone point out why does the method return an error? How to debug the issue? Are there any permissions I should be giving. Any help in the regard is highly appreciated.

--Ramakrishna.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V 2012 supports the previous WMI API, and I have successfully used it.  Hyper-V 2012 introduces a v2 API, but this is irrelevant to you.

CreateSwitchPort is a very straightforward call.  Here is an example in Python that is quite readable.  The Python call returns a tuple that the [out] parameters are added to.

```
    #Create a port on the vswitch.
    (new_port, ret_val) = switch_svc.CreateSwitchPort(
                                        Name=str(uuid.uuid4()),
                                        FriendlyName=vm_name,
                                        ScopeOfResidence="",
                                        VirtualSwitch=extswitch.path_())
```

Check that the VirtualSwitch parameter is valid.  I use a WMI query shown below to get this object.  It fails if the VirtualSwitch is not connected to an external NIC.  Is your query successful?

```
        return self._conn.Msvm_ExternalEthernetPort(IsBound='TRUE')[0]\
        .associators(wmi_result_class='Msvm_SwitchLANEndpoint')[0]\
        .associators(wmi_result_class='Msvm_SwitchPort')[0]\
        .associators(wmi_result_class='Msvm_VirtualSwitch')[0]
```

Next, look to see if the name Name parameter needs to be unique.  If you use a static name, the call might fail because of a naming conflict.

If none of this helps, then start inspecting the Hyper-V WMI objects in realtime.  You can use Python and the [WMI bindings for Python by Tim Golden](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I am able to create a switch port. But now I am facing an issue in attaching switch to the virtual machine. When I checked the event viewer I was getting "failed to add device 'Synthetic Ethernet Port'" error. What does this mean? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If the answer helped, then you need to accept it.  Post a new question, message me about it and I'll take a look.

Comment: I am sorry I should have mentioned it. Yes your reply was really helpful for me to understand how to create a switch port. I was not using GUID format for name parameter. It succeeded as soon as I passed a GUID instead of a name. Even the event viewer log was helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure if I can message you here or there is provision to send a msg. I am new to stack overflow. So I am adding a comment in this post. I have raised a new question on how to used AddVirtualSystemResources method. Please help me out in attaching a virtual network to a virtual  machine.

Comment: You need to accept the answer to the question I posted.  Click the check mark under the up/down arrows by the answer.  This enables me to make more edits, and it tells others that the answer is useful.